# Why is Android ContentObserver's onChange() not getting called?

Tags: android, sms, contentobserver

I am trying to create a ContentObserver that will inform me when an SMS is sent from my device.  When I use the following my onChange() gets called:

```
public static final Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms");
```

However, when I try to limit it to just sent SMS messages using this:

```
public static final Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
```

it does not work; the onChange() method simply doesn't get called.  Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
public static final Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms");
```

and check the type of the cursor

[Here](http://gbandroid.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/MobileSpy/src/org/ddth/android/monitor/observer/AndroidSmsWatcher.java) is an example code.

Comment: I have seen other SO questions where people were using content://sms/sent.  Is that no longer supported?

Comment: I think I saw that sample during my research but haven't tried it yet.  I will report back here after I have tested it.  Thanks.

Comment: it appears to get called now, but it is called multiple times.  Why is this?  I only want to handle it once, so how can I narrow down my test in the onChange() event so that I'm not processing it multiple times?

Comment: have you unregistered the observer?

Comment: also check that .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026547/android-content-observers-onchange-method-is-called-multiple-times

Comment: I unregister it in onDestroy().

Comment: a normal solution is to use a timer. Check the time interval between 2 call. If the interval is too short then do not perform the operation